# OCAML increment search substring size

Tags: string, for-loop, ocaml, increment, ref

This is the last time i post about this project, I am almost done with the project but I am stuck with the part where I have to increase the size of the substring being searched. This is the prompt of the program.

```
Description:
You are given a DNA sequence:
a string that contains only characters 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T'.
Your task is to calculate the number of substrings of sequence,
in which each of the symbols appears the same number of times.

Example 1:
For sequence = "ACGTACGT", the output should be 6
All substrings of length 4 contain each symbol exactly once (+5),
and the whole sequence contains each symbol twice (+1).

Example 2:
For sequence = "AAACCGGTTT", the output should be 1
Only substring "AACCGGTT" satisfies the criterion above: it contains each symbol twice.


Input: String, a sequence that consists only of symbols 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T'.
Length constraint: 0 < sequence.length < 100000.
```

This is my code`

```
let countA = ref 0 
let countC = ref 0 
let countG = ref 0  
let countT = ref 0  
let subStricount = ref 0
let tempH = ref 0  
let tempT = ref 3 

let countChar x = 
    match x with
        'A'-> countA := !countA +1;
    | 'C' -> countC := !countC +1;
    | 'T' -> countT := !countT +1;
    | 'G' -> countG := !countG +1;  
;;
let demoStri = read_line() in 
let striL = String.length demoStri in 
for i = 0 to striL -1 do 
    if !tempT < striL then
        for j = !tempH to !tempT do
            countChar demoStri.[j];
            if (countA = countC) && (countC = countG) && (countG = countT) then subStricount := !subStricount +1;
        done;
        countA := 0;
        countC := 0;
        countG := 0;
        countT := 0;
        tempH := !tempH +1;
        tempT := !tempT +1;
done;
if String.length demoStri > 4 then
    for i = 0 to String.length demoStri - 1 do
        countChar demoStri.[i];
    done;
if (!countA > 0) && (countA = countC) && (countC = countG) && (countG = countT) then subStricount := !subStricount + 1;


print_int !subStricount; print_string "\n";
```

`
This code runs fine counting the input of the string, for example ACGTACGT will return a 6, however it is only searching in substrings of 4, is there a way to code it so that after it searches an array of size 4, it increases the size until it reaches the size of the string itself?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually what you want to do is take this part of the code:

```
let tempH = ref 0  
let tempT = ref 3 

let striL = String.length demoStri in
. . .
if (!countA > 0) && (countA = countC) &&
   (countC = countG) && (countG = countT) then
    subStricount := !subStricount + 1;
```

And make it into a function of two parameters: `demoStri` and `substrLen`. Initialize `tempT` to `substrLen - 1`.

Then call the function for many different values of `substrLen`.

Comment: would that increment the substring size though? i know that if I could get the substring size to increase I could get rid of teh third for loop at the bottom, but getting their is what's difficult

Comment: You just need to find the parts of the code that depend on the substring length and make them depend on the parameter `substrLen` instead. This is the essence of programming (IMHO). It will definitely work, all software depends on this kind of abstraction :-)

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you mean, however, I tried putting it in a while, and now its giving me the wrong answer, I simply put the entire thing within a while loop, while !tempT < striL do...... and at the end I would have the tempT := !tempT - !tempH + 1; tempH:= 0; this successfully increases the size of the substring but it is returning the wrong result.

Comment: If you just put a `while` or `for` around your existing code, you can make it work as long as you reset everything that needs to be reset each time around. But you should work on thinking in terms of functions rather than straight-line code. (Unsolicited advice, I admit.)